# Unable to pass view model list in CSHTML to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a View Model, View, and Controller that works great displaying the data, but I cannot get the data entered in the form to save to the controller.  I've tried using a list, array, and a list for the view model.

Here's my view model:

```
public class AssignedHostData
{

    public int HostID { get; set; }
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Additional Details")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string AddDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the section of my view that displays the data:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        @{
            int cnth = 0;
            List<Support_Web.Models.ViewModels.AssignedHostData> hosts = ViewBag.Hosts;

            foreach (var host in hosts)
            {
                if (cnth++ % 1 == 0)
                {
                    @:</tr><tr>
                }
                @:<td>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                        name="selectedHosts[@cnth].HostID"
                        id="selectedHosts_[@cnth]_HostID"
                        value="@host.HostID"
                        @(Html.Raw(host.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                    @host.HostID @:  @host.HostName
                @:</td>
                @:<td>
                    <input type="text" name="selectedHosts[@cnth].AddDetails" id="selectedHosts_[@cnth]_AddDetails" value="@host.AddDetails" />
                @:</td>
            }
        @:</tr>
    }
</table>
```

And here're the parameters from my Edit controller. The `selectedProducts` list returns an empty list every time:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id, string[] selectedProducts, List<HostCheckListItem> selectedHosts)
```

Comment: Check out this link here, which explains how to create a form for a list of items:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My view needed to be formatted this way:

```
@{
                                        int cnth = 0;
                                        List<Support_Web.Models.ViewModels.AssignedHostData> hosts = ViewBag.Hosts;
                                        for (int i = 0; i < hosts.Count; i++)
                                        {
                                <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="checkbox"
                                                       name="selectedHosts[@i].HostID"
                                                       value="@hosts[@i].HostID"
                                                       @(Html.Raw(hosts[@i].Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                                                @hosts[@i].HostName
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="selectedHosts[@i].AddDetails" value="@hosts[@i].AddDetails" />
                                            </td>
                                    </tr>}
                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to transfer the modified model data list in the view to
>   the controller, you can use "asp-for" to bind in the form.

Please refer to the following for details:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{        
    private readonly MydbContext _context;
    public ProductController (MydbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Hosts = _context.AssignedHostData.ToList();
        return View();
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(List<AssignedHostData> Hosts)
    {
        List<AssignedHostData> selectedHosts = Hosts.Where(x => x.Assigned == true).ToList();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Edit.cshtml:

```html
<form asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Edit" method="post">

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            @{
                int cnth = 0;
                List<WebApplication_core.Models.AssignedHostData> Hosts = ViewBag.Hosts;

                for (int i = 0; i < Hosts.Count; i++)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" asp-for="@Hosts[i].HostID" />
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Hosts[i].Assigned" />

                        @Hosts[i].HostName
                        <input id="Hidden2" type="hidden" asp-for="@Hosts[i].HostName" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" asp-for="@Hosts[i].AddDetails" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            }
        </table>
        <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Edit" />
    </form>
```

Here is the debug result:
[image]